# What rig should I start with when trying to get hands-on experience with Fldigi?

Tags: digital-modes, software, equipment, fldigi

I would like to get hands-on experience with Fldigi. What setup is recommendable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nearly any SSB HF rig will do.

You need some way to get audio out of the receiver and into your computer, and out of your computer and into the transmitter. Most modern transceivers provide some kind of connection for this. In a pinch, you can use the headphone and microphone connections.

It's also convenient (through not necessary) if Fldigi can key the radio for you. With some fiddling, you can usually rig up something that uses one of the control lines on a serial port to control a relay or optioisolator to key the radio. Methods vary based on the radio, so just search the internets for a rig you are considering.

Even better is to get a rig which supports control over a serial connection. Fldigi uses [hamlib](http://hamlib.sourceforge.net/manuals/1.2.15/index.html), so anything supported by hamlib will work. Usually there's a serial port on the back of the radio, and if you don't have a serial port on your computer a USB cable can be had for $20 or so.

Get the list of supported radios by running `rigctl -l`. Your version might be different, but I get:

```
Rig #  Mfg                    Model                   Version         Status
    1  Hamlib                 Dummy                   0.5             Beta
    2  Hamlib                 NET rigctl              0.3             Beta
  101  Yaesu                  FT-847                  0.5             Beta
  103  Yaesu                  FT-1000D                0.0.6           Alpha
  104  Yaesu                  MARK-V FT-1000MP        0.0.5           Alpha
  105  Yaesu                  FT-747GX                0.4.1           Beta
  106  Yaesu                  FT-757GX                0.4.1           Beta
  107  Yaesu                  FT-757GXII              0.4             Stable
  109  Yaesu                  FT-767GX                1.0             Stable
  110  Yaesu                  FT-736R                 0.3             Stable
  111  Yaesu                  FT-840                  0.1             Untested
  113  Yaesu                  FT-900                  0.1             Untested
  114  Yaesu                  FT-920                  2010-08-23      Stable
  115  Yaesu                  FT-890                  0.1             Stable
  116  Yaesu                  FT-990                  0.2.1           Alpha
  117  Yaesu                  FRG-100                 0.4             Beta
  118  Yaesu                  FRG-9600                0.2             Untested
  119  Yaesu                  FRG-8800                0.2             Untested
  120  Yaesu                  FT-817                  0.5.1           Beta
  121  Yaesu                  FT-100                  0.4.1           Beta
  122  Yaesu                  FT-857                  0.4             Beta
  123  Yaesu                  FT-897                  0.3.3           Beta
  124  Yaesu                  FT-1000MP               0.1.1           Beta
  125  Yaesu                  MARK-V Field FT-1000MP  0.0.5           Alpha
  126  Yaesu                  VR-5000                 0.2             Alpha
  127  Yaesu                  FT-450                  0.22.1          Beta
  128  Yaesu                  FT-950                  0.22.2          Stable
  129  Yaesu                  FT-2000                 0.22.1          Stable
  130  Yaesu                  FTDX-9000               0.22.1          Untested
  131  Yaesu                  FT-980                  0.1             Alpha
  132  Yaesu                  FT-DX5000               0.22            Alpha
  133  Vertex Standard        VX-1700                 1.1             Alpha
  201  Kenwood                TS-50S                  0.8             Untested
  202  Kenwood                TS-440                  0.8.0.6.1       Alpha
  203  Kenwood                TS-450S                 0.8.1           Beta
  204  Kenwood                TS-570D                 0.8.2           Stable
  205  Kenwood                TS-690S                 0.8.1           Beta
  206  Kenwood                TS-711                  0.8.0.6.1       Untested
  207  Kenwood                TS-790                  0.8.2           Alpha
  208  Kenwood                TS-811                  0.8.0.6.1       Untested
  209  Kenwood                TS-850                  0.8.1           Beta
  210  Kenwood                TS-870S                 0.8.0           Beta
  211  Kenwood                TS-940S                 0.8.0.6.1       Alpha
  213  Kenwood                TS-950SDX               0.8             Beta
  214  Kenwood                TS-2000                 0.8.4           Beta
  215  Kenwood                R-5000                  0.6.1           Alpha
  216  Kenwood                TS-570S                 0.8.1           Stable
  217  Kenwood                TH-D7A                  0.5             Alpha
  219  Kenwood                TH-F6A                  0.5             Beta
  220  Kenwood                TH-F7E                  0.5.1           Beta
  221  Elecraft               K2                      20120615        Beta
  222  Kenwood                TS-930                  0.8             Untested
  223  Kenwood                TH-G71                  0.5             Beta
  224  Kenwood                TS-680S                 0.8.1           Beta
  225  Kenwood                TS-140S                 0.8.1           Beta
  226  Kenwood                TM-D700                 0.5             Beta
  227  Kenwood                TM-V7                   0.5             Beta
  228  Kenwood                TS-480                  0.8.5           Untested
  229  Elecraft               K3/KX3                  20120615        Beta
  230  Kenwood                TRC-80                  0.8             Alpha
  231  Kenwood                TS-590S                 0.8.1           Beta
  232  SigFox                 Transfox                20111223        Alpha
  233  Kenwood                TH-D72A                 0.5.1           Alpha
  234  Kenwood                TM-D710                 0.5             Untested
  302  Icom                   IC-1275                 0.7             Beta
  303  Icom                   IC-271                  0.7             Untested
  304  Icom                   IC-275                  0.7.1           Beta
  306  Icom                   IC-471                  0.7             Untested
  307  Icom                   IC-475                  0.7.1           Beta
  309  Icom                   IC-706                  0.7.1           Untested
  310  Icom                   IC-706MkII              0.7.1           Untested
  311  Icom                   IC-706MkIIG             0.7.2           Stable
  312  Icom                   IC-707                  0.7             Untested
  313  Icom                   IC-718                  0.7.1           Beta
  314  Icom                   IC-725                  0.7.1           Stable
  315  Icom                   IC-726                  0.7             Stable
  316  Icom                   IC-728                  0.7             Untested
  319  Icom                   IC-735                  0.7.1           Beta
  320  Icom                   IC-736                  0.7             Untested
  321  Icom                   IC-737                  0.7             Untested
  322  Icom                   IC-738                  0.7             Untested
  323  Icom                   IC-746                  0.7.1           Beta
  324  Icom                   IC-751                  0.7.1           Beta
  326  Icom                   IC-756                  0.7.1           Alpha
  327  Icom                   IC-756PRO               0.7             Untested
  328  Icom                   IC-761                  0.7.1           Stable
  329  Icom                   IC-765                  0.7             Stable
  330  Icom                   IC-775                  0.7.1           Untested
  331  Icom                   IC-781                  0.7.1           Untested
  332  Icom                   IC-820H                 0.7             Alpha
  334  Icom                   IC-821H                 0.7             Alpha
  335  Icom                   IC-970                  0.7             Untested
  336  Icom                   IC-R10                  0.7             Untested
  337  Icom                   IC-R71                  0.7             Untested
  338  Icom                   IC-R72                  0.7             Untested
  339  Icom                   IC-R75                  0.7             Beta
  340  Icom                   IC-R7000                0.7.0           Alpha
  341  Icom                   IC-R7100                0.7.0           Untested
  342  Icom                   ICR-8500                0.7.1           Beta
  343  Icom                   IC-R9000                0.7.1           Alpha
  344  Icom                   IC-910                  0.7.1           Beta
  345  Icom                   IC-78                   0.7             Untested
  346  Icom                   IC-746PRO               0.7             Stable
  347  Icom                   IC-756PROII             0.7             Alpha
  351  Ten-Tec                Omni VI Plus            0.2             Beta
  352  Optoelectronics        OptoScan535             0.3             Beta
  353  Optoelectronics        OptoScan456             0.3             Beta
  354  Icom                   IC ID-1                 0.7             Untested
  355  Icom                   IC-703                  0.7             Untested
  356  Icom                   IC-7800                 0.7.2           Untested
  357  Icom                   IC-756PROIII            0.7.1           Beta
  358  Icom                   IC-R20                  0.7             Untested
  360  Icom                   IC-7000                 0.7.2           Beta
  361  Icom                   IC-7200                 0.7             Beta
  362  Icom                   IC-7700                 0.7.1           Stable
  363  Icom                   IC-7600                 0.7             Beta
  364  Ten-Tec                Delta II                0.1             Untested
  365  Icom                   IC-92D                  0.7             Untested
  366  Icom                   IC-R9500                0.7.1           Untested
  367  Icom                   IC-7410                 0.7             Untested
  368  Icom                   IC-9100                 0.7             Untested
  369  Icom                   IC-RX7                  0.7             Untested
  401  Icom                   IC-PCR1000              0.8             Beta
  402  Icom                   IC-PCR100               0.8             Beta
  403  Icom                   IC-PCR1500              0.8             Beta
  404  Icom                   IC-PCR2500              0.8             Beta
  501  AOR                    AR8200                  0.6.1           Alpha
  502  AOR                    AR8000                  0.6.1           Beta
  503  AOR                    AR7030                  0.4.1           Beta
  504  AOR                    AR5000                  0.6.1           Beta
  505  AOR                    AR3030                  0.4             Untested
  506  AOR                    AR3000A                 0.5             Beta
  508  AOR                    AR2700                  0.6             Untested
  513  AOR                    AR8600                  0.6.1           Beta
  514  AOR                    AR5000A                 0.6             Alpha
  515  AOR                    AR7030 Plus             0.1             Beta
  516  AOR                    SR2200                  0.1             Beta
  605  JRC                    NRD-525                 0.1             Alpha
  606  JRC                    NRD-535D                0.6             Stable
  607  JRC                    NRD-545 DSP             0.6             Beta
  801  Uniden                 BC780xlt                0.3             Untested
  802  Uniden                 BC245xlt                0.3             Untested
  803  Uniden                 BC895xlt                0.3             Untested
  804  Radio Shack            PRO-2052                0.3             Untested
  806  Uniden                 BC250D                  0.3             Untested
  810  Uniden                 BCD-396T                0.3             Alpha
  811  Uniden                 BCD-996T                0.3             Alpha
  812  Uniden                 BC898T                  0.3             Untested
  902  Drake                  R-8A                    0.5.1           Beta
  903  Drake                  R-8B                    0.5             Untested
 1004  Lowe                   HF-235                  0.3             Alpha
 1103  Racal                  RA6790/GM               0.1             Untested
 1105  Racal                  RA3702                  0.1             Alpha
 1204  Watkins-Johnson        WJ-8888                 0.2             Untested
 1402  Skanti                 TRP8000                 0.2             Untested
 1404  Skanti                 TRP 8255 S R            0.1             Untested
 1501  Winradio               WR-1000                 0.6             Untested
 1502  Winradio               WR-1500                 0.6             Untested
 1503  Winradio               WR-1550                 0.6             Untested
 1504  Winradio               WR-3100                 0.6             Untested
 1505  Winradio               WR-3150                 0.6             Untested
 1506  Winradio               WR-3500                 0.6             Untested
 1507  Winradio               WR-3700                 0.6             Untested
 1601  Ten-Tec                TT-550                  0.2             Beta
 1602  Ten-Tec                TT-538 Jupiter          0.6             Beta
 1603  Ten-Tec                RX-320                  0.6             Stable
 1604  Ten-Tec                RX-340                  0.3             Untested
 1605  Ten-Tec                RX-350                  0.1             Untested
 1607  Ten-Tec                TT-516 Argonaut V       0.2             Stable
 1608  Ten-Tec                TT-565 Orion            0.5             Beta
 1609  Ten-Tec                TT-585 Paragon          0.3             Beta
 1611  Ten-Tec                TT-588 Omni VII         0.3             Alpha
 1612  Ten-Tec                RX-331                  0.1             Beta
 1613  Ten-Tec                TT-599 Eagle            0.4             Untested
 1701  Alinco                 DX-77                   0.7             Beta
 1801  Kachina                505DSP                  0.3             Alpha
 1901  Hamlib                 RPC rig                 0.3             Beta
 2201  TAPR                   DSP-10                  0.2             Alpha
 2301  Flex-radio             SDR-1000                0.2             Untested
 2303  DTTS Microwave Society DttSP IPC               0.2             Alpha
 2304  DTTS Microwave Society DttSP UDP               0.2             Alpha
 2401  RFT                    EKD-500                 0.4             Alpha
 2501  Elektor                Elektor 3/04            0.4             Stable
 2502  SAT-Schneider          DRT1                    0.2             Beta
 2503  Coding Technologies    Digital World Traveller 0.1             Untested
 2506  AmQRP                  DDS-60                  0.1             Alpha
 2507  Elektor                Elektor SDR-USB         0.3.1           Stable
 2508  mRS                    miniVNA                 0.1             Alpha
 2509  SoftRock               Si570 AVR-USB           0.2             Beta
 2511  KTH-SDR kit            Si570 PIC-USB           0.2             Beta
 2512  FiFi                   FiFi-SDR                0.5             Beta
 2513  AMSAT-UK               FUNcube Dongle          0.2             Beta
 2514  N2ADR                  HiQSDR                  0.2             Untested
 2601  Video4Linux            SW/FM radio             0.2.1           Beta
 2602  Video4Linux2           SW/FM radio             0.2.1           Alpha
 2701  Rohde&Schwarz          ESMC                    0.1             Alpha
 2702  Rohde&Schwarz          EB200                   0.1             Untested
 2801  Philips/Simoco         PRM8060                 0.1             Alpha
 2901  ADAT www.adat.ch       ADT-200A                1.36            Beta
```

Comment: Some additions. Most radios are marketted as "multi-mode" radios nowadays. Can't get wrong getting one of those. The mic and microphone connections will work but the radio must have a VOX feature. You also must disable the OS system sounds since those will be redirected to the radio. fldigi also uses other libraries not only hamlib. I, for one, use "RigCAT" for my rig. The CAT cable is needed specially for TX, for PTT switching. RX only, just route the output of the radio to your soundcard. Also, some older radios require RS-232 level signals.

Answer (score 1):

The rig only matters a little, more important is getting a good interface to your computer, and making sure that interface can support your rig. The two most common interfaces are SignaLink and the RigBlaster Pro, although there are other options. Basically you figure out how you want to connect the interface to your radio, and then you connect the interface to your computer via USB. I prefer to have one that has an aux port in the back. Most radios have the ability to do some kind of interfacing with this, although some may require you to set the radio in that mode to begin with.